# using an apostrophe

Tags: apostrophe

Should I use an apostrophe in the sentence "It is an insult to those of our, and our parents generation".  (parents, parent's or parents'?)
Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: The answer is *parents'*, since it is a plural possessive. However for this level of question you need to be asking on our sister site *English Language Learners - Stack Exchange.*

Comment: Surely this is a dupe.

Comment: should it not be "our and our parents' generations" -- no comma and plural generations, since by definition we and our parents cannot share a generation?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, it would be *parents'*.  The sentence refers to the generation "belonging to" all the parents.

The exception would be if the sentence is referring only to one parent shared by all the people referred to, in which case it would be *parent's*.